# Unresolved external symbol _sleep Using sleep()?

Tags: c, windows

I am trying to use the sleep() command.  I am using C on windows (visual studio compiler).  The command is simply `sleep(5);`  I have windows.h included, time.h, stdio.h.  What more do I need?

Answer (score 6):

You want [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx) (note the casing) as defined in the Windows API.  It's accessible through `Windows.h`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax to use sleep in Visual Studio compiler is given in windows library

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx

So for 5 seconds of sleep use

```
Sleep(5000);
```

You will also have to add the header file

```
Windows.h
```